# diff() fails on zoo object

Tags: r

While working on a new project in R, I wrote the following code:

```
sp500 <- get.hist.quote("^GSPC",start=(today <- Sys.Date())-735,quote="Cl")
lsp500 <- log(sp500)
rlsp500 <- diff(lsp500)
```

The problem is the diff() function, it produces the following error:

```
Error in MATCH(x, x) : could not find function "MATCH"
```

All other code executes without problems. I'm using RStudio and R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26) -- "Trick or Treat" on Mac OSX 10.8.2.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tseries_0.10-30

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.15.2     lattice_0.20-10 quadprog_1.5-4  tools_2.15.2    zoo_1.7-9
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please include the output from `sessionInfo()` in your question. I cannot reproduce the error on my system.

Comment: This is a good question, but changing the title to `diff() fails on zoo object` (and eliminating the R from the title, that information is carried by the [r] tag) would make it better ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tseries::get.hist.quote` returns a zoo object by default, but the tseries package doesn't attach zoo, so `zoo::MATCH` isn't found.  I assume `zoo::MATCH` is used in `diff.zoo` or one of the functions called by it.

Attaching zoo (via `library(zoo)`) will fix the problem.